# How can I extract the Author of the book using Jsoup?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I´m trying to extract the authors of the books at this Amazon page using Jsoup: [Link](https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=s9_acss_bw_en_BGG15eve_d_1_6_w?_encoding=UTF8&node=17&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-top-3&pf_rd_r=8Z2ERCN30FREH3ZD6AHC&pf_rd_r=8Z2ERCN30FREH3ZD6AHC&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=c0b03f4d-c947-45e3-9b66-2bd220509181&pf_rd_p=c0b03f4d-c947-45e3-9b66-2bd220509181&pf_rd_i=283155)

[image]

I have been able to scrape the tittles:

```
public static final String URL_LITERATURE_FICTION="https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=s9_acss_bw_en_BGG15eve_d_1_6_w?_encoding=UTF8&node=17&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-top-3&pf_rd_r=8Z2ERCN30FREH3ZD6AHC&pf_rd_r=8Z2ERCN30FREH3ZD6AHC&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=c0b03f4d-c947-45e3-9b66-2bd220509181&pf_rd_p=c0b03f4d-c947-45e3-9b66-2bd220509181&pf_rd_i=283155";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_LITERATURE_FICTION).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements link = doc.select(".s-result-list-parent-container > ul > li .s-access-title");
```

But I don´t know how to extract the authors. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with this selector: ".a-fixed-left-grid .a-fixed-left-grid-inner .a-row.a-spacing-none .a-size-small.a-color-secondary .a-link-normal.a-text-normal" ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea about how 
go through the different pages?

Comment: I think you can use the #pagnNextLink as selector to get the next page link.

Comment: Selector: "a.pagnNext" or "#pagnNextLink". Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the link you provide in the question, a valid DOM selector for your scraping needs is:

```
.a-fixed-left-grid .a-fixed-left-grid-inner .a-row.a-spacing-none .a-size-small.a-color-secondary .a-link-normal.a-text-normal
```